# Using Python to manipulate the GUI's of other programs?

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a program here that has an entry box and a button.

I want python to enter a string into the entry box, then press the button. What is the best way of going about this?

This is for windows 7, BTW.

Comment: platform is very important in this type of question

Comment: Just made the edit. I always leave out that part...

Comment: Not only platform. What kind of GUI? What's the program written in? If you just want a macro thing, autohotkey can do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyWinAuto will work nicely for this. With it you can "type" text into windows based on window title( or window class) as well as "click" buttons. Its fairly easy to use, and the website is pretty good about giving you examples on how to do what you want.

http://pywinauto.openqa.org/howto.html

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of, but not yet tried myself:

- [WATSUP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/watsup/)
- [Python Win32 GUI Automation, aka "pywinauto"](http://pywinauto.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: An anonymous suggested editor has pointed out that the link to WATSUP is dead.

Answer (score 0):

PyAutoGUI (installable through pip) can automate mouse/keyboard and works on Mac/Windows/Linux.

It also has some basic screenshot image recognition capabilities like Sikuli has.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI