# Navigating/working with through GUI applications with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a python module that will allow me to automate/work with Windows GUI applications? For example, I know that objects in most standard-gui windows apps have a unique `com` id that I can extract text from/click it/etc.

Things I would like to do:

- Retrieve list of items from List-tree
- Detect if specific gui objects exists in the other program exist (For the purpose of detecting if new screen/page has loaded)
- Click buttons/tabs

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301561/calling-autoit-functions-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Python to manipulate the GUI's of other programs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553050/using-python-to-manipulate-the-guis-of-other-programs)